# KNN on Spark dataframe with 15 Million records

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, knn

I have a Pyspark dataframe like this:

```
0   [0.010904288850724697, -0.010935504920780659, ...   
1   [0.34882408380508423, -0.19240069389343262, -0...
2   [0.13833148777484894, -0.23080679774284363, -0...   
3   [0.12398581206798553, -0.4803846478462219, -0....
4   [0.16033919155597687, -0.06204992160201073, -0.
```

Now I want to find 100 Nearest Neighbor for all this arrays.

Here's my try:

```
df_collect = df.toPandas()
features = np.array(df_collect.features.to_list())

knnobj = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=100).fit(features)
distance_mat, neighbours_mat = knnobj.kneighbors(features)
```

But as df is too big  it's taking too long. I know I can broadcast and parallelize the last step but I'm not able to find how to fit spark df to `scikit-learn` knn model. Is there any other way I can do it?

I also read some articles where they have mentioned about `ANN(Approximate Nearest Neighbor) Sparkit-Learn spark_sklearn` but I'm not able to find their implementation for Nearest Neighbor. Can anyone guide me what to do next

Answer (score 1):

1.Load the data only using libraries like datatable, cuDF or dask. They are always faster than Pandas.

2.Reduce the memory consumption by up to 90% by casting each column to the smallest subtype possible.

3.Choose a data manipulation library you are comfortable with or based on what you need.

4.Take a 10–20% sample of the data for rapid analysis and experimentation.

5.Think in vectors and use vectorized functions.

6.Choose a fast ML library like CatBoost for building baselines and doing feature engineering.